# Word document generation with jinja2 & flask without html tags

Tags: html, python-3.x

My current setup is this:

- HTML page with a form that maps to certain variables
- Variables are passed through to a flask route
- Flask/Python script uses a base word document template that is setup to generate a new word document that uses jinja2 to pass-through html form text.

This functionality is working fine. The problem is, it is including the html tags into the finished word document that the user downloads. I obviously don't want to display these html tags in the word document, just the text and ideally whatever formatting being used as well. Currently, I have tested html plugins such as CKEditor and TinyMCE however I am having the same problem. The main formatting I need to be able to do is: bold, italics, lists. If I can pass through this formatting from the html form to the word document without displaying the correlating html tags in the word document that would be great.

Is this possible? Cheers.

Comment: That is not trivial. The obvious attempt would be some sort of HTML-to-Word converter, but that's hard to combine with filling in a template. I assume you're using an actual Word template and fill it using some actual library that can process actual Word files; not something that just spits out HTML with a DOCX ending…? Then you probably need to parse the HTML received from the frontend, programmatically understand that it's bold/italic/whatever, and translate that into equivalent formatting instructions for that Word library…

Comment: Yes, it is an existing .docx file that is already populated save for the jinja2 variables I'm replacing. Unfortunately I've tried something like html2text but it adds a crazy amount of spacing and doesn't work well. It wouldn't be too bad to strip away all the tags, but then I'd need to tell python-docx to set the text that was in certain tags into bold/italic/whatever? (if python-docx even can do that).